# EMF2DOMAdapterImpl_ERROR_0 Websphere Application Server WAS (V8.5) DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: WEB-INF/web.xml

Tags: websphere, web.xml, was, deployment-descriptor

Websphere Application Server V 8.5 fails to startup with certain web.xml structure.

Current DOCTYPE uses http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error mainly occurs when there is a problem with the web.xml deployment descriptor.
This problem is caused because of invalid tag in the web.xml which can be due to multiple different things such as:

There should be no duplicate tages for

- session-config
- welcome-file-list
- jsp-config
- login-config
- locale-encoding-mapping-list

Web.xml is not supposed to have multiple url-pattern under one servlet-mapping tag in deployment descriptor. If you have around 3 - 4 url-patterns under one servlet-mapping, move this to multiple servlet mapping containing one url-patterns.

For more debug information you can check the logs in AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\server1\SystemErr